# PrincipalExistsException is thrown, but the Principal doesn't actually exist

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, directoryservices

Given the following code, why do I get a `PrincipalExistsException` when I know for a fact that the principal doesn't exist and isn't actually made?

```
public UserPrincipal Add(
    string givenName,
    string surname,
    string domain) {
    UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(context: base.Context) {
        Enabled = true
    };

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(givenName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(surname) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(domain)) {
        this.RenameInternal(principal: principal, givenName: givenName, surname: surname, domain: domain);

        principal.Save();
    };

    return principal;
}
```

I can confirm that the `RenameInternal()` method works just fine because it get's called by a method named `Rename()`. So, there must be an issue with how the object is created and/or saved, but I don't know how to find out where the error is. This seems like simple enough code...

Looking through the domain controller (Windows Server 2008 R2) I can't find the "newly" create principal anywhere, so I'm assuming that it's not being created and that the exception is lying to me somehow.

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The SamAccountName was what was causing the exception to be thrown (thank you Microsoft for the ever helpful error messages). Anyway, it was the issue because it was trying to set it to a name that already exists. I modified it by tossing in a middle initial and it's working fine, or at-least until I get people with the same first initial, middle initial and last name.

Comment: You can check this by opening the Find UI in Active Directory, creating a Custom Search on the Advanced tab and searching for "samaccountname=*<what_youre_trying_to_create>*".

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of off hand would be the following

Whatever ID your application is running under, needs to have "write" access to AD. Pretty much any ID can query AD but only ID's explicitly granted the privilege can write to it.

Comment: Well, I have a special account that has been given administrative rights. I even added the account to the `Domain Users` OU with read and write access, but it's still erring out. Using the exact same account I can create `GroupPrincipal`s without any issue.

Comment: Well, I've found out that it's coming from the `SamAccountName` property, which it won't let me change when creating. If I rename a `UserPrincipal` I've manually created in the domain controller I can change it, but if the `UserPrincipal` is created through my application it won't let me set it at creation time or rename it. WTF?